# How to decouple two classes elegantly in the following example?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Suppose we take the case of building a Vending machine using OOP principles.

Let us suppose we have an abstraction called VendingMachine.

```
class VendingMachine {
    List<Slot> slots; //or perhaps a 2-d matrix of slots
}
```

The VendingMachine class has a list of slots and each slot may have some capacity (to model say 5 items one behind the other).

Now how do I associate a Value ($) to a slot. Clearly each slot will have the same item so each slot should be associated with same value (or better an abstraction representing the item, say Item class).

But in terms of responsibility, the VendingMachine class should only be able to eject an item, or throw an exception when trying to eject an item from an empty slot. I think that it is not the responsibility of VendingMachine class to know what is the value of a particular slot.

How do I design this elegantly? Is there some design pattern that comes to your mind.

My solution is to create a class MoneyManager.

```
class MoneyManager {
    MoneyManager(VendingMachine vm);
    Pair<Slot, Item> mapping;
}
class Item {
    int itemCode;
    BigDecimal value;
}
```

Even if you think that the modelling is wrong, what I am more interested in knowing is how do you decouple 2 classes like that.

For example if you design a car parking lot, a class Vehicles should have information on how much space it takes (number of spots). A ParkingLot has information how much spots it has.

But I don't want the car to know in which ParkingLot it is parked and in which spot. Similarly I don't want the ParkingLot to maintain the state of what cars are parked and where. Should there be an intermediate class ParkingManager which maintains this state for a clean design?

Comment: Model what you need, no more no less. An unnecessary abstraction is worse than too little abstraction. Abstractions usually come from the language of the domain... I guess we could say that the machine **stock** or **inventory** has been replenished? You could also most likely manage the machine's **inventory** or **stock**. The stock/inventory concept could be important enough to be explicitely modeled, but do not introduce fictive abstractions or technical ones.

Comment: As I said above, I am more interested in learning how to decouple in such kind of a situation. This is a thought exercise.

Comment: You know how to decouple already as you just provided a solution. Other than that there is no one that can give you the right design for an hypothetical problem with no specific details.

Comment: okay I will work out the examples and post very specific problem if I am able to come up with one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is some kind of logic like a **wharehouse administration**.

Supposing all the slots and items are of the same size, you could probabbly break it out like this.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class Slot
{
    public int Capacity { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Warehouse
{
    public List<Slot> Slots { get; set; }
}
```

This is going to manage the **basic distribution of the items** in the warehouse. `Warehouse` class is going to manage the list of slots and `Slot` class is going to manage the list of items it contains.

Probably, if you need, **you could add sizes and locations** and add some logic of what kind of items fit the different slots.